# Firebase SimpleLogin (Facebook) Failing with Ionic on iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, cordova, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I've configured Facebook Login, and it works on desktop browsers. However, when using an actual iPhone connected to my laptop, two things happen:

- the first time I enter my login details (with Cordova in-app browser), Facebook gives me this page: http://cl.ly/image/0n3Z083o2H0j
- after I close and reopen the app, I look in GapDebug and see a request to something like https://auth.firebase.com/auth/facebook/callback?code=YDFasdfjsdfh893&fb_redirect_uri%22%3A%22file... with an error message "Failed to load resource: You do not have permission to access the requested resource."

It looks like the fb_redirect_uri is trying to get a file path instead of a URL -- is that right? Do I have a data access problem or what?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Is it possible this was a temporary problem related to an outage? There's not enough info here to troubleshoot on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what was going on, but I updated AngularFire and FirebaseSimpleLogin and then it worked.